# Score Doesn't work here? - Python

Tags: python, variables, python-3.3

I am trying to keep a score in this game, so I set a score variable and every time an answer is answered correctly, it adds + 1 point to score and if you get an incorrect answer, it will deduct a point. When i print score at the end, it is still equal to 0.

```
score = 0
q1answer = ("metallica", "slayer", "megadeth", "anthrax")

answerinput = str(input("name one of the 'Big Four' metal bands'"))

if answerinput.lower() in q1answer:
    print ("You got the right answer!")
    score + 1

else:
    print ("That is the wrong answer...")
    score - 1
print (score)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `score + 1` is just an expression and does not change the actual value of `score` variable. It's basically the same as saying `0 + 1`, since python will only get the value of `score` and add `1` to the value it received, not to the variable itself.

To fix this, you need to reassign `score` to match it's current value plus one: `score = score + 1` or a simpler version: `score += 1`. And to removing score, just use minus: `score = score - 1` or easier `score -= 1`

Answer (score 1):

`score + 1` and `score - 1` are just expressions; they don't actually do anything. To actually change `score`, use `score += 1` and `score -= 1`.

(Also, use a set! Curly braces! As mentioned earlier `;)`)